# Flatten a list of lists independent on content types and length and depth of sublists

Tags: python, list, flatten

I want to flatten such a list:

```
l = ["af", 2, [4.123, "ic", [-8, ["xdr"], -6]], [], [-2]]
```

The result should be:

```
f = ['af', 2, 4.123, 'ic', -8, 'xdr', -6, -2]
```

The list `l` and all sublists can have any length, can contain any type of data and can contain nested sublists of any depth.

I am not able to find any answered question regarding my problem and also I cannot find any package which contains the solution as a one-liner.

My simple code can do that what I want, but I am sure that a solution already must exiss.

```
l = ["af",2,[4.123,"ic",[-8,["xdr"],-6]],[],[-2]]
f = []
x = [1]

def flatten (val):
    if type(val) != type(x):
         f.append(val)
    else:
        for i in range(0,len(val)):
            flatten(val[i])

for i in range(0,len(l)):
    flatten(l[i])

print(f)

# output is ['af', 2, 4.123, 'ic', -8, 'xdr', -6, -2]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists

Comment: @Green Cloak Guy: Yes this solutions solves my question! So it seems that there is no build-in function which does the flattening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pydash 
l = ["af", 2, [4.123, "ic", [-8, ["xdr"], -6]], [], [-2]]
pydash.flatten_depth(l,-1)
# output: ['af', 2, 4.123, 'ic', -8, 'xdr', -6, -2]
```

Comment: You should consider adding this to the other question. Search for `deep_flatten` among the answers if you want another 3rd party library alternative